# Get attribute of property knowing what it is

Tags: c#, attributes

want to do something very simple and that is getting the attribute of a property. Now I know how to do this via PropertyInfo etc but I know the property I want to get the attribute of so is it possible to do something like:

```
MyAttribute attr = (MyAttribute)customer.Forename;
```

Ideally want to avoid reflection. Only way I can think of is doing a linq statement like:

```
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Customer).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == "Forename").FirstOrDefault();
MyAttribute attri = (MyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pi, typeof(MyAttribute));
```

Don't like this as I am having to do a string comparison on the property name :(

Considering I know the property I want to get the attribute of I thought there might be an easier way?

Comment: you are using reflection already in your code.

Comment: I want to avoid using that code that was just say I know of these approaches but ideally if I know the property already don't want to get all PropertyInfo[] find the one I want and get attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kzu wrote a piece of code to allow strongly typed reflection.

See a blog post here: http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/linq-beyond-queries-strong-typed-reflection/

You can now get it as a NuGet package (NETFx Reflector):

http://nuget.org/packages/netfx-Reflector

```
// Void static method
MethodInfo cw = Reflect.GetMethod(() => Console.WriteLine);

// Instance void method
MethodInfo mi = Reflect<IView>.GetMethod(v => v.Show);

// Boolean returning instance method
MethodInfo pi = Reflect<IViewModel>.GetMethod<bool>(v => v.Save);
```

Comment: Ah so no out of the box features in .NET was hoping for one :(

Comment: @No, not out of the box.